# Find the constraint force acting on the plane

Tags: classical-mechanics

An inclined plane of mass $m_1$ inclined at an angle $\theta$ lies on the $x$-axis. Let $(x,0)$ denote the position of the plane. A spring with spring constant $k$ is attached to the right of the plane. The spring is horizontal and unstretched when $x=0$. A block of mass $m_2$ slides without friction down the plane.

I'm asked to find the constraint force acting on the plane given that the tension in the spring is a conservative force.

**So far I have done the following:**

\begin{align*} m_1 \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} & = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -m_1g \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ N_2 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} N_1\sin\theta \\ -N_1\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} -T \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \\ & = \begin{pmatrix} N_1\sin\theta-T \\ N_2-N_1\cos\theta-m_1g \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

This gives $$N_1=\frac{T+m_1\ddot{x}}{\sin\theta}$$ and $$N_2=(T+m_1\ddot{x})\tan\theta+m_1g$$ where $N_2$ is the normal between the plane and the $x$-axis, and $N_1$ is the normal pointing inwards to the plane from the block $m_2$.

So the force of constraint acting on the plane is $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ N_2 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} N_1\sin\theta \\ -N_1\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} T+m_1\ddot{x} \\ m_1g \end{pmatrix}$$

Is this correct?[image]

Comment: Where are $m_2$ and $k$ in your equations?  Why is $T$ missing in your first line?  How are $N_1$ and $N_2$ defined?  Any chance to get a drawing?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I've made an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the drawing and the definitions.  What about the first two questions?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I didn't think I needed to consider $m_2$ since I'm only looking at the constraint force acting on the plane, is this incorrect? I'll make an edit to fix the missing $T$ in the first line.

Comment: $N_1$ depends on $m_2$ and $T$ depends on $k$ and $x$.  In the end, you need to substitute.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi How do I do that?

Comment: For $T$ you use Hooke's law, and for $N_1$ you decompose $-m_2g$ into components parallel to the inclined plane and perpendicular to it.